# Run a python script that is never Killed

Tags: linux, scripting, python, kill-process

I have a script running `python script.py` in a new screen but sometimes the script gets killed:

```
18
21
Restarting processes... done
2
Killed
```

How can I protect the script from being killed even when I close the console? Shall I use & or nohup?

Comment: Are you the sole administrator of the system?  I just did a quick test and that "Killed" output is not what is displayed when you send Python a `SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding this code to your script http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731-creating-a-daemon-the-python-way/

Or use screen.

Edit: This is a little more modern but I haven't used it(I use something custom) http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon

Comment: I use screen but the script seems to be killed without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it is running inside a `GNU screen` session? In this case, it shouldn't get killed unless there is some problem with the script and it terminates due to this problem.

If you don't use `screen`, use start using it or `tmux` (which I like more).

Comment: I use screen but the script seems to be killed without any error.

Answer (score 0):

A modern way to do it is using of the systemd. You just create the unit of service with `type=Simple` without any screen/tmux, and set the `restart=always` option to restart script at any unexpected exits.

Instead of the screen/tmux you also can use the `start-stop-daemon` - native tool for debian based systems to demonize applications. But restarting at exit you should implement with third-party tools like the monit.